# Is there way that I can get movie title names having a word in OMDb API

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Hi I am a newbie in Python. I am trying to query OMDb API.I want to find all the movies that is having the word 'Runner' in the title name.
Currently I am getting only Runner as the value

For example: there are 4 movie titles having names

- Runner
- He is a runner
- Runner,the story
- Bolt,a story of a runner

```
import json
import requests

from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Runner&apikey=[yourapikey]')



data = json.loads(r.text)

pprint(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?s=` instead of `?t=`.  The [docs say](http://www.omdbapi.com/?) that the `t` parameter is used for title, while `s` is used for search.